# Get email alerts from git commits in hybrid TFVC / Git Visual Studio Online project

Tags: git, tfs, tfs-2015, azure-devops, tfvc

The documentation [Set alerts, get notified when changes occur](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/track/alerts-and-notifications) shows how to set up email alerts so that I receive an email whenever `Anything is checked in`. The documentation makes the point that

> For Git repository-based team projects, `A commit is pushed to this team project` appears in place of `Anything is checked in`.

But since Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 1 we can add a Git repo to a team project created with Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Code/team-projects).

In a hybrid Visual Studio Online TFS project that hosts both a TFVC instance and a git repository how do we get email alerts from git commits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any way to achieve this for now. And there is already a feedback submitted on Microsoft Connection Page, refer to this link for details: [Alert categories missing for TFVC-created Team Projects with additional Git repositories](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2143391)

Comment: Thanks Eddie - I've given the issue a +1 [there](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2143391)

Comment: Eddie the linked feedback page details that the issue has been fixed, but doesn't specify in what version. Like @dumbledad we are running on premises version of *TFS 2105 Update 1*. Can I expect that this issue is fixed in Update 2?